# Is a simulation of the greenhouse effect and other temperature variations on earth possible?

Tags: atmospheric-science

I want to program a computer simulation of the earth in Python. For example, I can have the earth visible and near infrared albedo, the earth's middle infrared albedo, and from that I can get the temperature, then the other values can variate by $\text{CO}_2$ emissions, cloud variations, methane from the ice caps, ice formation etc. and see what happens when they feed back.

I want to know if it has already been done so I can use it.

Comment: I think you'll find the question is not "has it been done" but "How can I sift through the thousands of simulations people have made to find one that meets my particular requirements."

Comment: This is also a case of what you are trying to do.  Accurately modeling the temperature rise of the earth's surface as a function of greenhouse gases is VERY complicated, as there are feedbacks between ocean currents and the atmosphere, surface temperature and absolute humidity, absolute humidity and the type of cloud cover and the radiative effect of that cloud cover, etc.  I've heard that the Russians have a model that closely matches the actual temperature rise over the last 30-40 years while U.S. models over-estimate the temperature rise.